# How Can I Catch Ambiguous Xslt Template Matches Using the .Net Xsl Processor?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

As described in the original question, using the Saxon xsl processor with the input xml and xsl file from the link [XSLT Error produced "Ambiguous rule match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536828/xslt-error-produced-ambiguous-rule-match), the Saxon processor generates the ambiguous rule match error/warning.

I am trying to produce the same or a similar message via the .Net xsl processor, but I have been unsuccessful.  If anyone knows if this is possible, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code snippet I am using:

```
        XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

        XslCompiledTransform xsltTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
        XsltSettings xslSettings = new XsltSettings();
        xslSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;
        xslSettings.EnableScript = true;

        xsltTrans.Load(xslFile, xslSettings, resolver);

        XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = xsltTrans.OutputSettings;

        _xmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver = resolver;

        try
        {
            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(outFile, writerSettings))
            {
                using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(inputfile, _xmlReaderSettings))
                {

                    if (_xslArgs != null)
                    {
                        xsltTrans.Transform(xr, _xslArgs, xw);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xsltTrans.Transform(xr, xw);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (XsltException xslex)
        {
            sResult = string.Format("Error: XSLT Exception - {0} - Line {1} - {2}", Path.GetFileName(xslFile), xslex.LineNumber, xslex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Saxon generates a warning, not an error.

Comment: Thanks. Saxon treats warnings as errors if you set the RecoveryPolicy property to "DoNotRecover" (eg, transformer.RecoveryPolicy = RecoveryPolicy.DoNotRecover;).  At any rate, I'm looking for a way to produce this same warning/error with .Net

Comment: That Saxon produces a warning at all, and that it furthermore provides a mechanism to choose whether to abort or recover, are Saxon implementation details that go beyond the requirements for a conforming XSLT processor.  I don't know whether .Net's XSLT processor can be configured to behave similarly, but there's no *a priori* reason to suppose that it could be.

Comment: You will never get to the catch statement because the using statements will handle exceptions.  So you have to remove the using statements to produce the error condition.

Comment: @jdweng You are wrong. I have gotten to the catch statement outside of  each using statement.  Although this does not achieve my intended goal, if you insert <xsl:message terminate = "yes"> into one of the templates in the xsl file, the XsltException is thrown with the catch statement where it is. See (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129720).

Comment: I agree.  You are missing a Try around where the real error is occurring so  the wrong exception handler is getting the exception.  My comments where referring to the actual reading of the xml file and not the checking of the schema.